# Compute annual mean of values from a tuple using time information

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I have daily precipitation values with time information in following form:

```
a = [(19500101,3.45),(19500102,1.2).......(19701231,1.4)]
```

I want to take annual mean of it using date information. It might be a simple solution. I have tried as below. Any suggestions?

```
prcp=numpy.array(precipitation)
time=numpy.array(time)
yearly=numpy.zeros(prcp.shape)

#-----------------Get annual means-----------------
for ii in xrange(len(time)):
    tt=time[ii]
    if ii==0:
        year_old=tt[0:4]
        index_start=ii
    else:
        #----------------new year----------------
        year=tt[0:4]
        if year != year_old:
            year_mean=numpy.mean(prcp[index_start:ii])
            yearly[index_start:ii]=year_mean
            year_old=month
            index_start=ii

    #----------------Get the last year----------------
    if ii==len(time)-1:
        year_mean=numpy.mean(prcp[index_start:])
        yearly[index_start:]=year_mean
```

Comment: Can you show that what you have tried so far, till we can find the logic behind your request or perhaps the problems that you have been faced with  them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `Pandas` for aggregations.

```
import pandas as pd

a = [(19500101,3.45),(19500102,1.2), (19701231,1.4)]  
df = pd.DataFrame(a) # convert to dataframe                                
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], format='%Y%m%d') # create a datetime series    

df.groupby(df[0].map(lambda x: x.year)).mean() # groupby year and mean from g roups

          1
0
1950  2.325
1970  1.400
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the snippet below to do this:

First, segregate the data based on the years:

```
>>> list_of_data = [(19500101,3.45), (19500102,1.2), (19701231,1.4)]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in list_of_data:
...     data[str(item[0])[:4]].append(item[1])
```

And now, calculate the mean using

```
>>> for key, value in data.iteritems():
...     print key, sum(value)/len(value)
... 
1950 2.325
1970 1.4
```

Note that I am doing two runs on the data, and @John's answer of Pandas will be probably faster if you are ok using the pandas library.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `pandas` as @John-Galt suggested,

If you want a python solution without pandas:

```
import numpy as np
a = [(19500101,3.45),(19500102,1.2).......(19701231,1.4)]
year=lambda x:int(x[0]/10**4)
years={year(x) for x in a}
annual_avg=dict()
for y in years:
   annual_avg[y]=reduce(np.mean,[x[1] for x in a if year(x)==y])
```